# gcloud apps logs tail returns Internal Error. Logs GUI returns unknown error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm working on a project on Google App Engine and `gcloud app logs tail` stopped returning logs several hours ago. Currently, when I enter the command, I get `Waiting for new log entries...` for about a minute before it times out and returns `INTERNAL: Internal error encountered.` If I try accessing or querying logs through the Google Cloud console, there is a `Unknown Error has occurred` notification. It appears the server-side scripts are still working, as I can access the internal site running on App Engine just fine.

It does not appear that there is a service-level issue right now, but I need to see the logs as part of making sure my updates to the server-side code are running properly. Please advise how I should approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue now in Google Cloud Logging, please visit the [Google Cloud dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/) see the yellow banner at the top:

> Cloud Logging delays on log ingestion in the us-central1 region and 25% of the global region. Projects in us-central1 may experience failures running queries.

Google Cloud Engineering team is working on solving this issue. If there is no yellow banner, it should be completely fixed.

Comment: Thank you! I checked the dashboard and only saw an issue at us-central (I'm us-east), and when I reached out to Google Cloud they said there were no relevant service disruptions.

Comment: But it clearly was the issue you mentioned because logs are back up and running again.